# Как поставить две ссылки рядом друг с другом по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, ссылка

Как поставить две ссылки рядом друг с другом по горизонтали?
Подскажите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.float li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- По-умолачнию ссылки с display:inline, поэтому ссылки будут располагаться  -->
<div>
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
</div>

<!-- Обертка для ссылок или сама ссылка со свойством display:inline, будут вести как строчные снаружи (блочные внутри) -->
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Задать обертке display: flex  -->
<ul class="flex">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Обертка для ссылок или сама ссылка со свойством display: float (обтекание) -->
<ul class="float">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>


<!-- Разместить ссылки в таблице или для обертки для ссылок задать display: table, а ссылкам display: table-cell -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--   .... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Тэг `<a>` и так является строчным элементом и прекрасно ставит соседей рядом с собой.
Приведите пример где у вас это работает не так.

```html
<a href="">link 1</a>
<a href="">link 2</a>
```

Comment: Пробелма в том, что у меня между ссылками стоит div: <a href="dfdfdf">Служба поддержки</a>  <div class="tytityt">|</div>  <a href="asdsad">Политика конфиденциальности</a>  <br> <div class="kikido">Позвоните нам 8-800-555-01-21</div>

Comment: @JoRick приложите код в вопрос

Comment: @JoRick так замените его на span

Comment: @NocteFury это не является решением, если нужно именно `div`

Comment: Судя по символу внутри, спану там самое место.